# Trying to use MathJax in Phonegap App

Tags: android, cordova, mathjax, bower-install

I'm trying to use MathJax in my Phonegap App. I'm going to explain step by step what I actually do. If you can see where's my mistake, please, tell me.
Step 1
Write in cmd: `phonegap create text`
Step 2
Change directory: `cd TEST\www`
Step 3
Change directory: `bower install MathJax` (this takes a few minutes...)
Step 4
Edit index.html using Brackets

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="bower_components/MathJax/MathJax.js"></script>
<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],       displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    },
    "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
  });</script>
</head>
<body>
$a$
</body>
</html>
```

Step 5
Wonder why it doesn't work and why I don't see the letter "a" as a ecuation, instead of `$a$`
Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: The configuration has to come before MathJax itself so start with that. Also you should slim down MathJax.

Comment: It worked, yes. The <script> tags were in wrong order. How can I slim down MathJax? Thanks!

Comment: Try https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-grunt-cleaner